# Visualizing StyleCop and Code Analysis rules violations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, code-analysis, fxcop, stylecop

I'm setting up a project where we've decide to use StyleCop and VS2010 "Code Analysis" rules.

I've setup the build so both sets of rules are executed on every build. The problem is that developers on this project will **only** be able to see StyleCop and Code Analysis rule violations on build.

While authoring code the VS2010 code editor doesn't highlight rules violations like it would do for build errors. I'm afraid that means folks would end up authoring code for an extended period of time and than prior to checkin have to fix 100+ rules violations. I'd like to explore a more organic process.

After spending the better part of the last two weeks googling, I admit defeat. I've found "StyleCop for Resharper" that would provide inline code editor highlights for StyleCop rules violations. I was wondering if there's something similar for Code Analysis or if there are any other options for StyleCop?

Thanks,

-- Justin Angel

Comment: Just for you to know that recent StyleCop versions (starting from 4.5) will contain embedded R# integration (what is "StyleCop for Resharper" by now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing similar to `StyleCop for Resharper` for FxCop. StyleCop is looking only for style guideline violations, which means it need only look at source code, text files. FxCop performs analysis on compiled assemblies and looks at things like P/Invoke correctness, multiple calls to `Dispose`, unmanaged vs. managed API use, etc. While a tool could certainly perform such analysis of source (indeed, Resharper can help you with some, but certainly not all FxCop warnings), to do so fully would effectively require a compile. If you are compiling, then you might as well just use FxCop. By the way, Resharper is worth the money.